# InvalidOperationException was unhandled in VB.NET when debugging

Tags: vb.net

Dear fellow programmers,

Most of the time the debug works but in some moments when I try to debug this error shows: http://s11.postimg.org/ezs58e4lv/screen.png
http://postimg.org/image/406xwse6n/

What I do most of the time is that I just close that error and re-debug it. But I want to ask if that error will affect my published application and when that error comes to the scene, will the solution is the user will just close my app and restart it again? Seems inconvenient.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I think you must verify the constructor again .. and read this maybe will help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx